# Where to run MapReduce Job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In a Hadoop multinode cluster, where should the reduce jobs be executed from, the master node where the namenode is or are any node execute a reduce job?

Comment: link - https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mapreduce/hadoop it may be help you

Comment: any node can execute a reduce task

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Distribution like HDP(hortonworks data platform) or CDH(Cloudera)

- Then you have execute your job from the node which contains hadoop client.

If you have your own Hadoop Distribution then you have to execute it from NameNode

Comment: HDP and CDH are no different than "own Hadoop Distribution". Jobs always can run anywhere with a Hadoop client (including completely outside the cluster)